# How to setup the location element in web.config for Parallel with other Frameworks

Tags: servicestack

I'm reading [https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework][1] but it doesn't explain enough or give a solution example (or I just don't know of an an example in the SS github site I can see something like this working with ASP.NET MVC and using that location element).

So I don't understand this custom service path from a Solution/Project perspective in the location element.

Here's how my current Solution looks:

[image]

Just a bit about the above pic.  The MVC project that I created is that one I outlined in orange.  I added then the ServiceStack projects I'll need to work with (we want to work with the actual code from SS, not binaries).

So now I'm looking back at the web.config that sits in my MVC proj as you can see in the pic which is open.  So this "/api" for example, so what is that referring to?  Like Our "Service" that we are gonna expose is in a different project ..you see that at the top, the project Called ServiceInterface.

I'm trying to understand how this works for the location.  Location of what and how would I set that up in my solution here just for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CoffeeAddict

sorry, but   as a simple ServiceStack user like you,  I feel  the need to tell you

that   it is good to have  a lot of questions, but

1. Here is not private support, please  make meaningful questions for all the others.
2. Don't waste time of mythz. We expect from him to deliver the new ServiceStack version.

If he is successful, all of us we will be too.

P.M

down in the page that you mentioned [Run servicestack side by side with another web framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework)

there is an example of config [Example config file for Asp.Net 3.5 in /api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/ApiPath35/Web.config#L22).

Maybe it is not appropriate for you, but it is not true, that there is not example.

Also, these questions

[Running ServiceStack side by side with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110598/running-servicestack-side-by-side-with-mvc)

[Service Stack on MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361860/service-stack-on-mvc4/15651761#15651761)

the following is from you at Sept 25. It was answered from mythz.

[Setting up Web.config to work Side-by-Side with ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008011/setting-up-web-config-to-work-side-by-side-with-asp-net-mvc-4-location-tag-not)

Maybe you are not satisfied of course, but what to do about ? nothing.

check this also 
[ServiceStack.Host.Mvc / content / README.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/README.txt#L10)

Here 
a user's blog post [A mixed ASP.Net MVC 4 and ServiceStack reference project](http://kiwidev.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/a-mixed-asp-net-mvc-4-and-servicestack-reference-project/)

and his sample project in githup [DiffStack](https://github.com/diffused/DiffStack)

Comment: yup I've read all that.  I was asking if there was an example, no need to go ranting on me.

Comment: the problem is your documentation, which I've repeatedly told you needs to improve and be consolidated.

Comment: "Don't waste time of mythz. We expect from him to deliver the new ServiceStack version" ah so this is how you value customer feedback on your docs?  Nice.

Comment: you know this reminds me of Facebook a few years back.  Their lead got some feedback by MANY devs on the disorganized, lacking messed up docs.  Eventually after 5 years he realized maybe he should start listening and working with the consumers to improve it and taking in their ideas for improvement.  Don't take that kind of attitude if you want your API to be adopted heavily.

Comment: also that "Example config file for Asp.Net 3.5 in /api." is not what I"m asking for.  Do you have a solution that shows this setup.

Comment: "as a simple ServiceStack user like you"  what do you mean by that.  I told you I do read the docs and they're not doing the job.  What I'd like to hear from the stack team is "How can you help us make this better" or "sure let us try to get an example for that or lets update that page a little more, you are right, it's lacking and making a lot of assumptions" but all I hear is "you sucks or you aren't reading" in sum.

Comment: In fact her'es an idea.  On support pages such as https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework why not have a bucket that lists related SS questions about this.  Rather than me searching and hunting them down in SO.  Take a look at TWitter's API.  There is a good example of good documentation.

Comment: @CoffeAddict.  What to do about ?  Documentation can be better,  a lot of things can be better. But this is the life. I work 9 months with serviceStack, and I asked only  7 questions.   I can assure you that now the situation is much better than before 9 months.  BTW, I think mythz  should thank you, because you compare Facebook with ServiceStack.   I wish to have the same success.

Comment: @CoffeeAdict  check this also [ServiceStack.Host.Mvc / content / README.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/README.txt#L10)

Comment: I use ServiceStack,  not working,  my bad English, don't misunderstand me

Comment: yes I've seen that read-me and it's snippets.  There needs to be actual entire global.asax example.  Anyway..thanks but I did see that already and tried to go by that and my global.asax still is not right.  There needs to be a working example.

Comment: "a lot of things can be better". It starts with documentation, that's the FIRST thing people see.  That's the MOST important thing on an API site period as well as builds that do not fail.  Those are the MOST important thing to expose.  Documentation should not be a "fix or update later"

Comment: BTW, I do not see FB's API as successful.  Many devs hate it just for these reasons (not consistent, docs are random, topics are not clear and all over the place).  Just look it up, so no I would not model by FB.  Anyway.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict  Here is a user's blog post [A mixed ASP.Net MVC 4 and ServiceStack reference project](http://kiwidev.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/a-mixed-asp-net-mvc-4-and-servicestack-reference-project/) and the sample project in githup [DiffStack](https://github.com/diffused/DiffStack)

Comment: christ, thanks, yet another thing to throw in the mix, power pack.  Thanks I'll check it out DiffStack.

Comment: @DiffStack please tell me you HAD this trouble when you first started, I hardly doubt I'm the only one.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict  if you are succesful with this user's project , please, edit your question text, adding at the end, the solution, so it could be meaningful and helpful to others.

Comment: Stefan, sure.  But what I want to know is if ServiceStack can only be used via dlls in reality.  You can never really rely on the true source that's hosted on github, only the dlls.  That's the way it's seemingly happening.  If that's the case then ServiceStack is no use to me if I can't get a meaningful working buill of source, and have to be forced to rely on dlls.  That gets us nothing.  We are not gonna host an enterprise API based on dlls that we have no control over.  The whole point of exposing an API is you expose working code & releases that are based on revision #s that are supported

Comment: @CoffeeAddict [DiffStack](https://github.com/diffused/DiffStack)  is the name of the project. You can ask user Kiwidev directly in his [blog](http://kiwidev.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/a-mixed-asp-net-mvc-4-and-servicestack-reference-project/)

Comment: Don't use ServiceStack, if you think it is not for  enterprise. From my experience, I use it as a part of bigger solution, in a hosted contact center 24/7.

Comment: @Stefan..."if you thing it is not for enterprise".  It's not about I think.  I'm trying to determine/confirm from all this pain, if the true reality of ServiceSTack is this:  That you can use the compiled assemblies in your product via NuGet but if you try and venture out and use it for an "API" meaning you try using the source code (which is why you expose a public API in the first place) that in reality for ServiceSTack, you can't use that source code...so really it's all about the dlls it looks like to me here (only  mythz can truly answer this question.) based off a core of dlls?

Comment: so if you can only rely on dlls here, what's the point of using SS?  What's the point of SS hosting this on GitHub other than to publish new dlls?  I don't get it.  Most devs building any kind of serious app in a company is going to want the source code as well in case they have to fix, extend or anything!  who just relies on a core of dlls like this if they want it to be their underlying service core?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, for me the point of using SS, is that it supports  all our architecture  in a complex highly demanding product. this value is superior than the problems. Also the web services architecture helps a lot the separation of concerns and actual work between developers.

Comment: I am not questioning what it can do for you...I see it as great which is why I wanted to use it but looks like I've waste time whic is frustrating to anyone and misleading.  I'm saying nobody is going to just use dlls from an open source API if the source code is technically never stable...that you have to rely on only the dlls being "working".

Comment: so let me get this straight, you guys are only consuming the dlls rihgt?  You haven't downloaded the source code, that means you're not adding .csproj references to your solution, you are just adding binary references to stack's NuGetted dlls right?  If that's the case, that proves my point.  If you want to bet your company's core code on dlls which you have no ability to extend, fix yourself, that defeats the entire purpose of exposing an open source API on GitHub.  Devs want the code in half the cases...code proj refs not assembly so they have a piece of mind but the source code must WORK!

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, 1.  in reality you don't  "waste time which is frustrating to anyone and misleading". But I think you could be more calm and patient.  2.  you ask " you guys are only consuming the dlls right ?". NO  But at least speaking for me.   for the 6 first months I built applications, APIs that they work,  reading only, few times the source code, to understand better the functionality.   the LAST 3 months only I built the source code and tests, debug.  also the last 40 days I answered SO questions, trying to return the favor for the people here who helped me.

Comment: I've been patient. I have posted patiently for a while and after a certain point, if mythz isn't gonna fix things frustration will set in with anyone.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict  as you probably know already ver.3 is BSD Free, the new ver.4 will have a  commercial   licence   (AGPL\FOSSException license).   So  the support and the package will be improved for an already excellent product.  the ver.3  will continue to be free with (BSD license). As a user,  I would prefer to continue to be in BSD free, but all of us we have a lot of demands for the team.